Как реализовать частичное обновление Android программ?
Как реализовать обновление программы, и что для этого надо , часто видел такое как частичное обновление приложения в андроид. но не могу понять с чего начать и как реализовать. Использую Delphi 11.
Из того что нашел там информация только о загрузке апк на сервер и скачивания его для обновления, но это не частичное обновление а полное.

Что вы понимаете под частичным обновлением? Если нужно обновлять какое то БД или ресурсы (видео, картинки и тд) что мешает это сделать сейчас?

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Google Play занимается этим самостоятельно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338332/partial-update-in-apk-instead-of-downloading-full-apk-again
